# Stash / Commit before Pull Not to Lose Local Files

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I'm having trouble with syncing my local repo with the remote repo on GitHub if both remote and local repos have changes. So, for example, if I haven't started working on a feature, before I start I can sync by simply running

```
git pull origin master
```

This is a simple one. However, while I am working on a feature on local, let's say my coworker had pushed new features to the remote so that the remote has changed also. I tried accomplishing syncing with both commiting and stashing before pull. So those codes,

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git pull origin master
```

or

```
git stash save "message"
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

Both those two methods ended up with overwriting my local changes, so rather than putting the remote changes on the top of my local master branch, it overwrites my local files and the local changes dissepear.

What am I doing wrong ? I was referring to many documentation about git but I just can't accomplish that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you're working on `my_branch`, and made some changes there. Now your co-worker pushes to the master, you need to update yours:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull
```

Your `master` is synced with the changes.

Now you want to continue working on `my_branch`, so you

```
git checkout my_branch
```

and now you should `stash pop` the changes:

```
git stash pop
```

If no conflicts were detected, the merge will automatically work. Otherwise, you'll be asked to resolve them.

Comment: So the problem I'm having is both stashing and pulling in the master branch, as I see. That really makes sense. So, I tried in your way. Unfortunatelly, this time the new feature on the repo didn't show up on my local repo. After last command "stash pop" do I need something like "git merge master" ?

Comment: Sure, you need to merge the changes from the remote master.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Let me try and I will write back the result.

Comment: I assume, because I tried after I pop the stash, it gives the error telling "you need to commit or stash". So, I again stashed and run "git merge master". It worked, but after I tried to again stash pop, it tried automatically merge where I encountered with conflict. But of course, that is an another issue, so I drop the question here. Hope I can solve it. Thanks for your great helps!

Comment: @KutayDemireren I'm glad it helped you. Solving the conflicts is what you need to do now :) I advise you to keep synced with the master to avoid huge conflicts in the future.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I will keep it mind. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting your branch to exactly match the remote branch can be done in 2 steps:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If you want to save your current branch's changes before doing this , you can do:

```
git commit -a -m "Saving my work, for later use"
git branch my-saved-work
```

Now your work is saved on the branch "my-saved-work" in case you decide you want it back (or want to look at it later or diff it against your updated branch).

Comment: reset seems dangerous to me in this situation, I actually don't want to count on reset here. Thanks anyway